# Pick a sms message from inbox

Tags: android, android-intent

I am a new android programer that i want to write an application that when an user is selecting a sms message, then that message is sent to my application.
I know that i must write an intent filter for my application like this

```
<intent-filter >
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the message and send it.

Here is a example link. [Read SMS Message](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/android-reading-inbox-sms.html)

Comment: I read it but i want to add a new option to messageOptions, this option named as my application. when the user chose it my application is invoked.